# Использование ссылок, полученных в результате парсинга страницы с помощью jsoup

Tags: ссылки, jsoup, html, java, синтаксический-анализ

Коллеги, продолжаю задавать свои веселые вопросы :)
В прошлом топе задавал вопрос, как со страницы получить ряд ссылок, в адресе которых присутствует afisha (тренируюсь на Yandex). Код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.yandex.ru").get();
            Element mBody = doc.body();
            String name = doc.title();
            System.out.println("Name of page html: " + name);

            Elements urls = mBody.getElementsByTag("a");
            for(Element url : urls)
            {
                if (url.toString().contains("://afisha"))
                    System.out.println(url);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Теперь изучаю методы для использования полученных адресов для последовательного перехода по ним (цель - проверка рабочего состояния ссылок). 
Желаю всем хорошего дня, сильного мозга, только положительных мутаций и Thanks God, It's Friday!